# how to find out the valid store names for certutil

Tags: windows-xp, scripting, command-line-interface

I'm trying to find a way to script installing a certificate.

Going "right-click->install certificate" works, and shows the certificate under 'subordinate certification authorities' in IE's certificate view

If found the certutil.exe command,

```
certutil.exe -addstore -enterprise <storename>
```

My question is how do you list/find out the valid storenames?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found a site with the valid store names which are:

```
ca -> Specifies certificates in the Intermediate Certification Authorities store
my -> Specifies certificates issued to the current user
root -> Specifies certificates in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store
spc -> Specifies software publisher certificates
user_created_store -> Specifies the name of a user-created certificate store
```

Comment: `certutil -addstore “Root” “c:\cacert.cer”` for ***Trusted Root Certification Authorities***

Comment: Question: command `certutil -addstore “CA” “c:\cacert.cer”` for ***Intermediate Certification Authorities*** in _LocalMachine_ ?

Answer (score 15):

You can quickly get the list in Powershell:

```
PS> ls Cert:\LocalMachine

Name : TrustedPublisher
Name : ClientAuthIssuer
Name : Remote Desktop
Name : Root
Name : TrustedDevices
Name : WebHosting
Name : CA
Name : REQUEST
Name : AuthRoot
Name : TrustedPeople
Name : My
Name : SmartCardRoot
Name : Trust
Name : Disallowed
```

Comment: Now *this* should be the accepted answer. Did not realize you could iterate over them like a file system.

Answer (score 10):

also:

- AddressBook -> specifies "Other People" store
- Trust -> specifies "Enterprise Trust" store
- TrustedPublisher  -> specifies "Trusted Publishers" store

by the way, "spc" is not working for me

I think the list is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename.aspx

or here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services2.security.x509.x509certificatestore_members.aspx

"root" and "trust" are not valid in the user context (when using **-user** switch)

Answer (score 7):

This will enumerate all certificate stores:

```
certutil -enumstore
```

[certutil -enumstore output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwFg1.png)

Check this answer for naming discrepancies:
[Certutil naming mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62646567/5516320)